# Making Dirt Texture in GIMP

Tags: gimp, texture, mobile

I'm making a mobile game. The game requires dirt/rock textures. I tried making a dirt Texture in GIMP using a bump map filter and a tried the different filters for creating the random noise. The result was not bad but not what I was looking for. It was to detailed. A good example of something along the lines of what I want is [image: (Crazy Driller)] Is there a good way of creating such type of textures in GIMP.

Comment: The above background seems generated by a vector program, is your final image? Can you please post an example of the effect you have actually achieved in order to compare it with the desired one?